# Cant access my Email address after run of uipath robot

Tags: email, outlook, uipath, uipath-activity

I have a problem with my email address since the last run of the UiPath robot. My program is sending around 20 emails through the smtp activity. Note that it worked before. UiPath is giving me the following error:

> mailkit.net.smtp.smtpcommandexception: cannot establish ssl with smtp
>   server, ssl_connect error 5

This address is part of a company mail domain. And note that the email is also configured into outlook on the laptop, and we also can’t connect on outlook anymore.

I tried to send an email through the console and it worked.
Also, the email smtp config doesn't require any certificate.

EDIT ONE:

[image: My uipath program error]

[image: error on outlook]

Comment: It seems like you tried to often to connect and now being blocked on those purposes. What happend if you login to the browser outlook? Is there any info about that? And what happens if you use the alternative activity. There you do not have to input the credentials. Instead if takes the installed Outlook from your computer. Did you already try that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. I havent tried. ill try it asap and get back to you. But the outlook app on the laptop is still blocked. cant access it

Comment: ok, i added outlook activity inside the finally in my try catch, but still getting nothing.......

Comment: btw i cant open it in outlook in browser because i dont have any microsoft or outlook id, i just have the company email on my outlook.

Comment: So does that mean you cannot access your email account anywhere anymore? Sorry but that does not make sense at all. Please add images.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply again, i edited my post and added error messages pictures

Comment: even we cant change any parameters about this email into outlook, its saying something went wrong. This happened since the last run of the robot..... But weirdly we ran the robot last month without any problem,

Comment: It pretty much looks like an issue on your server. I'm not professional on email. Please add those email tags here. As it's more related to an email issue instead of UiPath. Hope you find it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answers. I am not expert on emails as well and this leave me without answer. I'll add the tags. Cheers.